# Hover Effect for Font Awesome Icon Not Working

Tags: css

I am having a hard time figuring out how to make the Facebook icon glow like the Twitter and Instagram icons do when hovered over. The border that surrounds the Facebook font glows and changes color but not the icon itself.

This is how I have the font awesome icon in HTML:

```css
.wrapper ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper ul li {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #D8E2DC;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper ul li .fab {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: #D8E2DC;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.wrapper ul li:hover.facebook {
  border: 5px solid #3b5998;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #3b5998;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li:hover .fab-facebook-f {
  color: #3b5998;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #3b5998;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li:hover.twitter {
  border: 5px solid #00aced;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #00aced;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li:hover .fab-twitter {
  color: #00aced;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #00aced;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li:hover.instagram {
  border: 5px solid #bc2a8d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #bc2a8d;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li:hover .fab-instagram {
  color: #bc2a8d;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #bc2a8d;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="S animated bounceInUp">
    <ul>
      <li class="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li class="twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li class="instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I really need help, I've spent hours trying to fix it and I don't understand.

Comment: Your CSS selector is `fab-facebook-f` but your class is `fa-facebook-f`. Make them match and it will probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled the class name here:

```
.wrapper ul li:hover.facebook {
  border: 5px solid #3b5998;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #3b5998;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

It should be:

```
.wrapper ul li:hover.Facebook {
  border: 5px solid #3b5998;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #3b5998;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Preview it here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chiragbhansali/h18ont4h/5/)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to update the name of the `css` class into `facebook` instead of `Facebook`, check code snippet bellow:

```css
.wrapper ul {
list-style: none;
}
.wrapper ul li {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 20px;
margin: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 3px solid #D8E2DC;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
float: left;
}
.wrapper ul li .fab {
font-family: FontAwesome;
color: #D8E2DC;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 0;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
font-size: 25px;
}
.wrapper ul li:hover.facebook {
border: 5px solid #3b5998;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px #3b5998;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.wrapper ul li:hover .fab-facebook-f {
color: #3b5998;
text-shadow: 0 0 15px #3b5998;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.wrapper ul li:hover.twitter {
border: 5px solid #00aced;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px #00aced;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.wrapper ul li:hover .fab-twitter {
color: #00aced;
text-shadow: 0 0 15px #00aced;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.wrapper ul li:hover.instagram {
border: 5px solid #bc2a8d;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px #bc2a8d;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.wrapper ul li:hover .fab-instagram {
color: #bc2a8d;
text-shadow: 0 0 15px #bc2a8d;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="S animated bounceInUp">
<ul>
<li class="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
<li class="twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
<li class="instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```